# Why is the number of iterations in this nested for-loop a tetrahedral number?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop

I have the following nested for loop:

```
int N = 3;
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
    {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Increasing `N` gives us `counter` = 1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, 84, ..., which are all [tetrahedral numbers](https://www.mathsisfun.com/tetrahedral-number.html). Why is that? I see the formula

(n(n + 1)(n + 2)) / 6

where, in this example, n = (N - 2) because of the indexing (`i`, `i + 1`, and `j + 1`). But I don't understand why that is the case? What's the math behind this?

Comment: Perhaps start with a simpler case, two nested loops. What kind of special numbers are generated? Can you draw them?

Comment: I actually found a pretty good explanation in chapter 1 section 4 of [Algorithms](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/). It actually has the problem that originally prompted my question-- find the number of triplets that sum to a given value. Still, I tried the two-loops experiment and found that it produces the triangular number sequence, which now makes sense.